# which Client ID should I create in Google developer console ?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api, gmail-api

I am programming a console application which in run on a server. I have the users' gmail address and password, and the app is to use Gmail api to get the gmail information.Should I using oAuth or something else, and which type Client ID is the right choose? web app, server account or installed app?

if you can answer in Chinese, I will be more appreciate! Thank you!

Comment: https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Answer (score 2):

You can not get the user's emails from Gmail inbox without OAuth. So, first you need to create a web application on Google Developer Console to start with. Use these credentials for OAuth2 cycle and get the use authorization which will generate a pair of access_token and refresh_token. Use this pair to make calls to Gmail API and get user's email later on.

Go through the Gmail API guide at:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/

Comment: OAuth has a "resource owner password credentials" ,can I use it call gamil API?  Is there a way to call gmail API without users' authorization.

Comment: There is no way to access user's emails without OAuth unless you are using Google Apps Domain in which case, domain admin can access users mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question because its a console application you should create a `Client ID for native application`.

**You should also know**

You cant use email and password to access any of the Google APIs anymore on April 20 2015 [client login was shut down](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.dk/2015/02/reminder-clientlogin-shutdown-scheduled.html).

You will need to use Oauth2 request authentication from your users, save the refresh token.  Once you have saved refresh tokens for each of your users you will be able to run your console application by using the refresh token to get a new access token.